# Cannot submit a website form through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

This is the second post on Stack Overflow on my quest to access this godforsaken website: https://portal.mcpsmd.org/guardian/home.html

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class WebAccessor  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("https://portal.mcpsmd.org/public/");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("fieldAccount"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("fieldPassword"));

        // Enter something to search for
        username.sendKeys("");
        password.sendKeys("");

        WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("btn-enter"));
        submitBtn.click();

        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works on Facebook

I am sure that my button is being pressed as when I click submit, the site URL changes from

https://portal.mcpsmd.org/public/
to
https://portal.mcpsmd.org/guardian/home.html

When I type in usernames and passwords, (actual user and pass cannot be disclosed for obvious reasons), the password line actually tacks on another 20 or so characters to the end of the password field. (You can see this by typing in any random username and password and clicking submit).

This has lead me to believe there is some sort of front-end encryption going on. Is there any feasible way to log in?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, may you tell me what is your landing page (after success login)

Comment: https://portal.mcpsmd.org/guardian/home.html#/termGrades

Comment: @JSwang : That's fine it it extends, when you try your code what is the exception you are getting ?

Comment: @cruisepandey im not generating any exceptions other than the supposed non-critical CSS errors, It's just that after i submit my form, the driver.getTitle() returns the same string as before the form submission.

Comment: after submit , just wait for some time then use driver.getTitle() , it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to lack of credentials, my answer is just a bet.

But i think you should redirect after login, with a little tweak to avoid exceptions, like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class WebAccessor  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebClient WEB_CLIENT = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        WEB_CLIENT.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        HtmlPage loginPage;
        try {
            loginPage = WEB_CLIENT.getPage("https://portal.mcpsmd.org/public/");
            HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='LoginForm']");
            loginForm.getInputByName("account").setValueAttribute("YOURPASSWORD");
            loginForm.getInputByName("pw").setValueAttribute("YOURPASSWORD");

            loginForm.getElementsByTagName("button").get(0).click();

            HtmlPage landing = WEB_CLIENT.getPage("https://portal.mcpsmd.org/guardian/home.html#/termGrades");
            System.out.println(landing.getTitleText());
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

My output is: Student and Parent Sign In. But if you set correct attributes, it should be ok.

Comment: Your solution seems solid, however... There is a slight error...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64248231392su3p/Exception.txt?dl=0

Could be the form still not being submitted?

Comment: HtmlUnit doesn't handle Javascript very well... perhaps you have to login through WebRequest (emulating headers and cookies).. check this:  [Analyze Http Headers, form data.](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)

Comment: here you can find three different methods to login through htmlunit (check 2nd one): [htmlunit-login-example](http://scrapemania.blogspot.com/2016/10/htmlunit-login-example-form-submit-html.html), also consider cookies.. which you can inspect through firefox or chrome real browser